# Android DownloadManager: How can I get the response headers?

Tags: android, http, header, download-manager

Here is the response's header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 37888
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=g4tidw45yqwztc55nv0zdu55; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
**filename=%e5%85%a5%e5%ad%a6%e6%b3%a8%e6%84%8f%e4%ba%8b%e9%a1%b9.doc**
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2012 06:24:36 GMT
```

I can get this header via a software called Wireshark.

Here is DownloadManager in Java code:

```
lastDownloadId = manager.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
                            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setTitle("MyTest")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDescription("Something Useful")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "abc.doc"));
```

and I want get the header in Java code, so I can get the filename of this response.

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the `DownloadManager` honour the `Content-Disposition` header? You can check if the local file names matches the header. If not, you will have to download the file directly with `HttpClient` or `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: All right, thank you! I will check the filename before user click the download button. Thank you again. It's a little bit more complex to use HttpClient or HttpURLConnection.